# IP address error while invoking URL through form post request

Tags: visualforce, html, http, ip

I am invoking an external URL through HTML form post request.

Sample :

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://website.com/action.php" method="POST" target="abcd">
      <input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="Sam" />
      <input type="hidden" name="city" value="NYC;" />
      <input onclick="window.location.href = abcd type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
```

I am showing the button Submit Request and as user clicks on it, the request is triggered, and I am using the target id to open a new tab with the response.

This is working fine inside VDI(my client network which has been whitelisted. Salesforce IP ranges have also been whitelisted). However , it is throwing IP error when I am invoking from outside the IP range.

Why is it taking my system IP? Should it not take Salesforce server IP?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is responsible for taking the Visualforce and transforming it/rendering it as HTML, which gets sent to your browser.

The actions you take on the page itself therefore originates from your computer, not from Salesforce's servers. You'd observe the same thing if you tried to use Javascript (and/or LWC/Aura) to actually make the request to the external site.

If you want this to originate from a Salesforce IP address, you'll need to make a callout using Apex (in a controller, extension, or `@AuraEnabled` method if you're using LWC/Aura).

Comment: Thanks Derek for the information. Can I make a form post request from controller ? Or requests from controllers will be actual HTTP requests?Also , if I have action = url (middleware which will be hosted in IP range), will that also be throwing IP error?